# Unable to load json file in html using d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js, bubble-chart

I want to load data from a json file in an HTML file and use D3 to visualize it. I am able to view the data in the browser if the file is loaded on its own. The file is also received correctly verified by the 200 status. But the contents of the file are interpreted as null.

Here are the contents of the json file -

[{"totdistance":[[1987,20926761],[1988,81974990],[1989,93470285],[1990,116938068],[1991,128179520],[1992,123889922],[1993,113169123],[1994,119145135],[1995,132070386],[1996,145689003],[1997,158173093],[1998,164900616],[1999,180094162],[2000,191005263],[2001,186583998],[2002,185726579],[2003,189239126],[2004,203622782],[2005,200373825]],"routes":[[1987,45399],[1988,180871],[1989,195588],[1990,216314],[1991,219896],[1992,199066],[1993,176756],[1994,177851],[1995,194508],[1996,203001],[1997,206304],[1998,203071],[1999,209496],[2000,219160],[2001,209979],[2002,196111],[2003,189519],[2004,195939],[2005,197853]],"code":"HP","name":"HP","avgdelay":[[1987,16],[1988,8],[1989,11],[1990,12],[1991,12],[1992,7],[1993,11],[1994,15],[1995,17],[1996,23],[1997,17],[1998,29],[1999,25],[2000,28],[2001,18],[2002,9],[2003,13],[2004,25],[2005,18]]}]

Here is the code that tries to load the file and read its contents -

d3.json("flights.json", function(flights) {

But I get error on the console that flights is null.

I have tried running this code on a webserver using IE, Firefox and Chrome. But no solution.

I am using this as a starting point - https://github.com/mbostock/bost.ocks.org/blob/gh-pages/mike/nations/index.html

Here is the error -
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'map' of null

The json is valid as per http://jsonlint.com/

Thanks for any help to fix this issue.

Comment: code snippets rarely help, you need to post meaningful code samples or fiddler links so we can help

Comment: I am able to load it just fine. Can you post your complete code?

Comment: also if you could post a link to the actual json file... If you are passing the json lint from copy and pasting the json, it is possible that the encoding on the file or your text editor could be adding invalid characters in the file, leading to parse errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have switched to version 2.8 and it is working fine. One thing I noticed was that I was calling one variable as avgdelay and that was an issue. Once I renamed the variable to another one, d3 had no problems. I think it is kind of weird. But as of now, it has fixed the problem I was facing. I am closing the question.

Answer (score 1):

according to [this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests), the correct syntax of `d3.json` is

```
d3.json('URL', function(error, json) {
```

so it appears you might be trying to access the error argument, which if there is no error, could be null.

Comment: After trying with v3, I am now trying with v2 to see if that makes a difference. It seems there is some issue with json and I am not able to figure it out. I get the error in Chrome - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' and in Firefox, I get the error - [13:19:11.701] SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' @ http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js?2.8.1:2950.

Comment: Here is the json file - Here is my json file - [{"totdistance":[[1987,20926761],[1988,81974990],[1989,93470285],[1990,116938068],[1991,128179520],[1992,123889922],[1993,113169123],[1994,119145135],[1995,132070386],[1996,145689003],[1997,158173093],[1998,164900616],[1999,180094162],[2000,191005263],[2001,186583998],[2002,185726579],[2003,189239126],[2004,203622782],[2005,200373825]],

Comment: json file continued (restriction on number of characters) -"routes":[[1987,45399],[1988,180871],[1989,195588],[1990,216314],[1991,219896],[1992,199066],[1993,176756],[1994,177851],[1995,194508],[1996,203001],[1997,206304],[1998,203071],[1999,209496],[2000,219160],[2001,209979],[2002,196111],[2003,189519],[2004,195939],[2005,197853]],"code":"HP","name":"HP","avgdelay":[[1987,16],[1988,8],[1989,11],[1990,12],[1991,12],[1992,7],[1993,11],[1994,15],[1995,17],[1996,23],[1997,17],[1998,29],[1999,25],[2000,28],[2001,18],[2002,9],[2003,13],[2004,25],[2005,18]]}]

Comment: you don't need to paste your json value if it passes the json lint validator. It's really no use in the comments.